# Building Hibernate from sources fails using "gradlew build"

Tags: hibernate, gradle

I would like to investigate multiple Hibernate issues, so I want to add test cases to the project as recommended here:

https://in.relation.to/2018/06/04/best-way-write-hibernate-orm-issue-test-case/

1. I forked the Hibernate repo https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm to my own one
2. I used the fork URL to connect to that repo from Eclipse (GIT perspective, `Ctrl+V`)
3. I imported the Gradle project into Eclipse from where I locally saved the GIT repo
4. I opened an Eclipse terminal (dir `C:\projects\hibernate-orm`)
5. Execute `gradlew build` from that dir, see below

This fails with

```
C:\projects\hibernate-orm>gradlew build
[WARN] Skipping Java module path integration tests because the JDK does not support it

> Configure project :hibernate-agroal
Maven settings.xml file did not exist : C:\Users\Kawu\.m2\settings.xml

> Configure project :hibernate-c3p0
Maven settings.xml file did not exist : C:\Users\Kawu\.m2\settings.xml

> Configure project :hibernate-core
Maven settings.xml file did not exist : C:\Users\Kawu\.m2\settings.xml

> Configure project :hibernate-enhance-maven-plugin
Maven settings.xml file did not exist : C:\Users\Kawu\.m2\settings.xml

> Configure project :hibernate-envers
Maven settings.xml file did not exist : C:\Users\Kawu\.m2\settings.xml

> Configure project :hibernate-graalvm
Maven settings.xml file did not exist : C:\Users\Kawu\.m2\settings.xml

> Configure project :hibernate-gradle-plugin
Maven settings.xml file did not exist : C:\Users\Kawu\.m2\settings.xml

> Configure project :hibernate-hikaricp
Maven settings.xml file did not exist : C:\Users\Kawu\.m2\settings.xml

> Configure project :hibernate-jcache
Maven settings.xml file did not exist : C:\Users\Kawu\.m2\settings.xml

> Configure project :hibernate-jpamodelgen
Maven settings.xml file did not exist : C:\Users\Kawu\.m2\settings.xml

> Configure project :hibernate-osgi
Maven settings.xml file did not exist : C:\Users\Kawu\.m2\settings.xml

> Configure project :hibernate-proxool
Maven settings.xml file did not exist : C:\Users\Kawu\.m2\settings.xml

> Configure project :hibernate-spatial
Maven settings.xml file did not exist : C:\Users\Kawu\.m2\settings.xml

> Configure project :hibernate-testing
Maven settings.xml file did not exist : C:\Users\Kawu\.m2\settings.xml

> Configure project :hibernate-vibur
Maven settings.xml file did not exist : C:\Users\Kawu\.m2\settings.xml

> Configure project :hibernate-ehcache
Maven settings.xml file did not exist : C:\Users\Kawu\.m2\settings.xml

> Configure project :hibernate-entitymanager
Maven settings.xml file did not exist : C:\Users\Kawu\.m2\settings.xml

> Configure project :hibernate-infinispan
Maven settings.xml file did not exist : C:\Users\Kawu\.m2\settings.xml

> Configure project :hibernate-java8
Maven settings.xml file did not exist : C:\Users\Kawu\.m2\settings.xml

> Task :hibernate-core:compileTestJava
C:\projects\hibernate-orm\hibernate-core\src\test\java\org\hibernate\query\hhh12076\AnnotationMappingJoinClassTest.java:46: error: duplicate class: org.hibernate.query.hhh12076.AnnotationMappingJoinClassTest
public class AnnotationMappingJoinClassTest extends BaseCoreFunctionalTestCase {
       ^
C:\projects\hibernate-orm\hibernate-core\src\test\java\org\hibernate\query\hhh12076\Claim.java:15: error: duplicate class: org.hibernate.query.hhh12076.Claim
public class Claim {
       ^
C:\projects\hibernate-orm\hibernate-core\src\test\java\org\hibernate\query\hhh12076\EwtAssessmentExtension.java:9: error: duplicate class: org.hibernate.query.hhh12076.EwtAssessmentExtension
public class EwtAssessmentExtension extends SettlementExtension {
       ^
C:\projects\hibernate-orm\hibernate-core\src\test\java\org\hibernate\query\hhh12076\Extension.java:11: error: duplicate class: org.hibernate.query.hhh12076.Extension
public abstract class Extension {

...

C:\projects\hibernate-orm\hibernate-core\src\test\java\org\hibernate\query\hhh12225\VehicleContract.java:12: error: duplicate class: org.hibernate.query.hhh12225.VehicleContract
public class VehicleContract extends Contract {
       ^
C:\projects\hibernate-orm\hibernate-core\src\test\java\org\hibernate\query\hhh12225\VehicleTrackContract.java:9: error: duplicate class: org.hibernate.query.hhh12225.VehicleTrackContract
public class VehicleTrackContract extends VehicleContract {
       ^
C:\projects\hibernate-orm\hibernate-core\src\test\java\org\hibernate\query\hhh13670\HHH13670Test.java:32: error: duplicate class: org.hibernate.query.hhh13670.HHH13670Test
public class HHH13670Test extends BaseCoreFunctionalTestCase {
       ^
C:\projects\hibernate-orm\hibernate-core\src\test\java\org\hibernate\query\hhh13712\HHH13712Test.java:32: error: duplicate class: org.hibernate.query.hhh13712.HHH13712Test
public class HHH13712Test extends BaseCoreFunctionalTestCase {
       ^

...

  symbol:   class Customer_
  location: package org.hibernate.jpa.test.metamodel
C:\projects\hibernate-orm\hibernate-core\src\test\java\org\hibernate\jpa\test\criteria\basic\PredicateTest.java:23: error: cannot find symbol
import org.hibernate.jpa.test.metamodel.Order_;
                                       ^
  symbol:   class Order_
  location: package org.hibernate.jpa.test.metamodel
C:\projects\hibernate-orm\hibernate-core\src\test\java\org\hibernate\jpa\test\criteria\ManipulationCriteriaTest.java:23: error: cannot find symbol
import org.hibernate.jpa.test.metamodel.Customer_;
                                       ^
  symbol:   class Customer_
  location: package org.hibernate.jpa.test.metamodel
C:\projects\hibernate-orm\hibernate-core\src\test\java\org\hibernate\jpa\test\criteria\mapjoin\MapJoinTest.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
import org.hibernate.jpa.test.metamodel.MapEntityLocal_;
                                       ^
  symbol:   class MapEntityLocal_
  location: package org.hibernate.jpa.test.metamodel
C:\projects\hibernate-orm\hibernate-core\src\test\java\org\hibernate\jpa\test\criteria\mapjoin\MapJoinTest.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
import org.hibernate.jpa.test.metamodel.MapEntity_;
                                       ^
  symbol:   class MapEntity_
  location: package org.hibernate.jpa.test.metamodel
C:\projects\hibernate-orm\hibernate-core\src\test\java\org\hibernate\jpa\test\criteria\OnKeywordTest.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
import org.hibernate.jpa.test.metamodel.LineItem_;
                                       ^
  symbol:   class LineItem_
  location: package org.hibernate.jpa.test.metamodel
C:\projects\hibernate-orm\hibernate-core\src\test\java\org\hibernate\jpa\test\criteria      symbol:   variable Order_
  location: class PredicateTest
C:\projects\hibernate-orm\hibernate-core\src\test\java\org\hibernate\jpa\test\criteria\basic\PredicateTest.java:260: error: cannot find symbol
                Path<Integer> integerPath = orderRoot.get( Order_.customer ).get( Customer_.age );
                                                                                  ^
  symbol:   variable Customer_
  location: class PredicateTest
C:\projects\hibernate-orm\hibernate-core\src\test\java\org\hibernate\jpa\test\criteria\basic\PredicateTest.java:260: error: cannot find symbol
                Path<Integer> integerPath = orderRoot.get( Order_.customer ).get( Customer_.age );
                                                           ^
  symbol:   variable Order_
  location: class PredicateTest
C:\projects\hibernate-orm\hibernate-core\src\test\java\org\hibernate\jpa\test\criteria\basic\PredicateTest.java:285: error: cannot find symbol
                        criteriaQuery.where( builder.isFalse( root.get( CreditCard_.approved ) ) );
                                                                        ^

                                 ^
  symbol:   variable Order_
  location: class CriteriaToScrollableResultsFetchTest
C:\projects\hibernate-orm\hibernate-core\src\test\java\org\hibernate\jpa\test\criteria\fetchscroll\CriteriaToScrollableResultsFetchTest.java:178: error: cannot find symbol
                predicates.add( idPath.get( OrderLineId_.purchaseOrgId ).in( ids ) );


...


  symbol:   variable Customer_
  location: class ManipulationCriteriaTest
C:\projects\hibernate-orm\hibernate-core\src\test\java\org\hibernate\jpa\test\criteria\ManipulationCriteriaTest.java:169: error: cannot find symbol
                                root.fetch( Customer_.spouse );
                                            ^
  symbol:   variable Customer_
  location: class ManipulationCriteriaTest
C:\projects\hibernate-orm\hibernate-core\src\test\java\org\hibernate\jpa\test\criteria\ManipulationCriteriaTest.java:196: error: cannot find symbol
                subCriteria.select( builder.avg( subQueryCustomerRoot.get( Customer_.age ) ) );
                                                                           ^
  symbol:   variable Customer_
  location: class ManipulationCriteriaTest
C:\projects\hibernate-orm\hibernate-core\src\test\java\org\hibernate\jpa\test\criteria\ManipulationCriteriaTest.java:201: error: cannot find symbol
                                                customerRoot.get( Customer_.age ),
                                                                  ^
  symbol:   variable Customer_
  location: class ManipulationCriteriaTest
C:\projects\hibernate-orm\hibernate-core\src\test\java\org\hibernate\jpa\test\criteria\mapjoin\MapJoinEntryTest.java:53: error: cannot find symbol
                        MapJoin<Customer, String, CustomerOrder> orderMap = customer.join( Customer_.orderMap );
                                                                                           ^
  symbol:   variable Customer_
  location: class MapJoinEntryTest
C:\projects\hibernate-orm\hibernate-core\src\test\java\org\hibernate\jpa\test\criteria\mapjoin\MapJoinTest.java:37: error: cannot find symbol
                MapJoin<MapEntity, String, MapEntityLocal> cname = entity.join(MapEntity_.localized);
                                                                               ^
  symbol:   variable MapEntity_
  location: class MapJoinTest
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
100 errors

> Task :hibernate-core:compileTestJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':hibernate-core:compileTestJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.5.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 12s
16 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 13 up-to-date

C:\projects\hibernate-orm>
```

**QUESTION**:

Why is this failing out-of-the-box?

I see there are a lot of metamodel classes involved etc.

Do I really have to cleanup (delete) the respective files?

What am I doing wrong? Any commands I'm missing? I'm feeling really stupid right now...

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem, causing the build to fail with

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

 * Where:
 Script '/Users/ejl/git/hibernate-orm/gradle/published-java-module.gradle' line: 78

 * What went wrong:
 A problem occurred evaluating script.
 > Cannot add task 'javadocJar' as a task with that name already exists.
```

I fixed it by removing my locally installed gradle in "/Users/ejl/.gradle".